# Where am I having errors with this Switch control structure in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a function using Javascript that according a received value (a mark) returns to you the qualification of this mark, according to the Spanish educational system. The code is the following one:

```
function calculateSpanishClassAverageMark(averageMark) {
    console.log("me muestra mi nota media", averageMark);
    var markText = " ";

    switch (averageMark) {
        case 10:
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido una matrícula de honor"
            break;
        case averageMark >= 9 && averageMark < 10:
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un sobresaliente"
            break;
        case averageMark >= 7 && averageMark < 9:
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un notable"
            break;
        case averageMark >= 6 && averageMark < 7:
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un bien"
            break;
        case averageMark >= 5 && averageMark < 6:
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un suficiente"
            break;
        case averageMark >= 4 && averageMark < 5:
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un insuficiente"
            break;
        case averageMark < 4:
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un muy deficiente"
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return console.log("Marktext", markText);
}
```

The first `console.log` shows `me muestra mi nota media 7.625`so the averageMark parameter is being received. However, the `console.log` that I return shows the following stuff: `Marktext`  . I have tried to debug, and the behavior is that when the program gets to the switch, it goes directly to the default option, so it does not change the value of `markText`. Where am I making an error? I dont understand why if the `averageMark` value is `7.625`, why it doesnt enter in that case of the switch. Thanks.

Comment: A `switch` statement compares the value of the expression in the header (in your case, the value of `averageMark`) with the computed value of each `case` expression. Your boolean expressions will evaluate to `true` or `false`, so they will never be `===` to the original expression. You should review the syntax and semantics of `switch` statements.

Comment: I have been reviewed and yes, the problem is I am comparing a Number (7.625) with a boolean ((averageMark >= 7 && averageMark < 9)). How could I solve it to do this comparison in a proper way? I dont have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: Well there are times when a `switch` is not the best way to do things; a series of `if` statements would be simpler.

Comment: Yes, but I used a switch because I thought it would be the cleaner way to do with this case (the other idea was an if-else but I thought the switch would be cleaner). So, would it be impossible to do this with a switch?

Comment: The `switch` statement is for picking out *particular* values, not ranges.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know if I could work with ranges with the switch statement. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The switch statement is for picking out particular values, not ranges.

This is true, but there's a trick to use `switch` as range selector. Obviously if `averageMark` isn't a number between 0 and 10 the switch will pick the `default` option or if is higher than 10 will pick the second case.

```js
function FirstCalc(averageMark) {
    
    var markText = " ";
    switch (true) {
        case (averageMark == 10):
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido una matrícula de honor"
            break;
        case (averageMark >= 9):
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un sobresaliente"
            break;
        case (averageMark >= 7):
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un notable"
            break;
        case (averageMark >= 6):
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un bien"
            break;
        case (averageMark >= 5):
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un suficiente"
            break;
        case (averageMark >= 4):
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un insuficiente"
            break;
        default:
            markText = "Esta clase ha obtenido un muy deficiente // default option !" 
            break;
    }

    return averageMark + " // " + markText;
}

$('#firstRes').append(FirstCalc(0) + '<br/>');
$('#firstRes').append(FirstCalc(2) + '<br/>');
$('#firstRes').append(FirstCalc(4) + '<br/>');
$('#firstRes').append(FirstCalc(6) + '<br/>');
$('#firstRes').append(FirstCalc(8) + '<br/>');
$('#firstRes').append(FirstCalc(10) + '<br/>');
$('#firstRes').append(FirstCalc(55) + '<br/>');
$('#firstRes').append(FirstCalc(1.25) + '<br/>');
$('#firstRes').append(FirstCalc("word") + '<br/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstRes"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `switch` statement is for picking out particular values, not ranges.